# Elisp: Conditionally change keybinding

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm trying to write a custom tab completion implementation which tries a bunch of different completions depending on where the point is. However, if none of the conditions for completions are met I would like tab to do what ever the current mode originally intended it to do.

Something like this:

```
(defun my-custom-tab-completion ()
  (interactive)
  (cond
   (some-condition
    (do-something))
   (some-other-condition
    (do-something-else))
   (t
    (do-whatever-tab-is-supposed-to-do-in-the-current-mode))) ;; How do I do this?
```

Currently I'm checking for specific modes and doing the right thing for that mode, but I really would like a solution that just does the right thing without me having to explicitly add a condition for that specific mode.

Any ideas of how to do this?

Thanks! /Erik

Comment: See the documentation for `define-key` and `local-set-key`. This is typically done by modifying mode-specific key-map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use functions such as `key-binding` (or its more specific variants `global-key-binding`, `minor-mode-key-binding` and `local-key-binding`) to probe active keymaps for bindings.

For example:

```
(call-interactively (key-binding (kbd "TAB")))
;; in an emacs-lisp-mode buffer:
;;    --> indent-for-tab-command
;; 
;; in a c++-mode buffer with yas/minor-mode:
;;    --> yas/expand
```

---

One way to avoid infinite loops if your command is bound to <kbd>TAB</kbd> could be to put your binding in a minor mode, and temporarily disable its keymap while looking for the <kbd>TAB</kbd> binding:

```
(define-minor-mode my-complete-mode
  "Smart completion"
  :keymap (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
            (define-key map (kbd "TAB") 'my-complete)
            map))

(defun my-complete ()
  (interactive)
  (if (my-condition)
      (message "my-complete")
    (let ((my-complete-mode nil))
      (call-interactively (key-binding (kbd "TAB"))))))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The problem here is that I would like to bind the command to tab, so key-binding would actually return the function itself, and hence cause an infinite loop. Could I look up the binding in the "original" key map for the mode somehow?

Comment: You're right, this is not easily done. See my edit for a possible workaround.

Comment: For a minor mode, you don't need to remove the entry from `minor-mode-map-alist`: you can just let-bind the minor-mode variable (aka `my-complete-mode`) around the call to `key-binding`.

Comment: @Stefan Could you post a code snippet showing what the let binding could look like to avoid having to remove the entry?

Comment: @Stefan nice idea, thanks. I edited my answer to take this into account.

Comment: Thanks! Good thing I had to learn about writing my own minor modes as well :)

Answer (score 6):

BTW, here is another solution:

```
(define-key <map> <key>
  `(menu-item "" <my-cmd> :filter ,(lambda (cmd) (if <my-predicate> cmd))))
```

Comment: Can you give an example of how to use this? What should `<map>` be for instance? And what is `menu-item` / why is it necessary here?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: `<map>` should be whichever map where you want to add that (conditional) key-binding.  E.g. your major mode's map.  `menu-item` is just a special symbol that needs to be where I put it for this to work.  This "menu-item + :filter" was originally added in order to be able to dynamically build particular (sub)menus (e.g. the menu containing the list of buffers and frames), hence the name; but since menus are implemented using keymaps it happens to work for non-menu elements as well.

Comment: Thank you! That helped, and almost works for me. I did something like: ``(add-hook 'gfm-mode-hook '(lambda () (progn (define-key gfm-mode-map (kbd "`") `(menu-item "" markdown-insert-code :filter ,(lambda (cmd) (if mark-active cmd)))))))`` The problem I see is that with this, the meaning of the key, when the predicate is not true, seems to be picking up the global keybinding (`self-insert-command` in this case), rather than the mode-specific one.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: [ Please don't quote your lambdas! ] Indeed what you did is override the mode-specific binding with a conditional binding, to use this technique, you'd need to add the conditional binding to some other map.  But in your case, it's probably not the technique I'd recommend.

Comment: What would you recommend? (As far as I can tell, my situation is exactly a special case of this question: I'd like to learn a general technique to, in a given mode, bind a key to either a custom function (if a certain predicate is true), or else the mode's default keybinding. Unfortunately I'm having trouble figuring out the solution you're trying to explain :-) Should one add the key-binding to the mode's map or not, for instance?)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a macro I wrote based on [Emacs key binding fallback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494096/emacs-key-binding-fallback) to define a keybinding conditionally. It adds the keybinding to the specified minor mode but if the condition is not true, the previously assigned action is executed:

```
(defmacro define-key-with-fallback (keymap key def condition &optional mode)
  "Define key with fallback. Binds KEY to definition DEF in keymap KEYMAP, 
   the binding is active when the CONDITION is true. Otherwise turns MODE off 
   and re-enables previous definition for KEY. If MODE is nil, tries to recover 
   it by stripping off \"-map\" from KEYMAP name."
  `(define-key ,keymap ,key
     (lambda () (interactive)
        (if ,condition ,def
          (let* ((,(if mode mode
                     (let* ((keymap-str (symbol-name keymap))
                            (mode-name-end (- (string-width keymap-str) 4)))
                       (if (string= "-map" (substring keymap-str mode-name-end))
                           (intern (substring keymap-str 0 mode-name-end))
                         (error "Could not deduce mode name from keymap name (\"-map\" missing?)")))) 
                  nil)
                 (original-func (key-binding ,key)))
            (call-interactively original-func))))))
```

Then I can do things like the following to use the special binding for TAB only when I am on a header in outline-minor-mode. Otherwise my default action (I have both indent and yasnippets) is executed:

```
(define-key-with-fallback outline-minor-mode-map (kbd "TAB") 
  (outline-cycle 1) (outline-on-heading-p))
```

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that you could achieve this without any special workarounds at all. In most modes `TAB` just does indentation by default, but if you set the global variable `tab-always-indent` to `'complete` it will try to do completion first, and indent if no completion is possible. This usually works really well, although if `TAB` is bound to another command in one of your major modes you might be out of luck.

If that works in the modes you need, you'll just need to add your custom completion function to the front of the list `completion-at-point-functions` in all applicable buffers (maybe using a mode hook). The `completion-at-point` command calls each function listed in `completion-at-point-functions` until one of them returns non-`nil`, so all you need to do to have your custom completion function "fall through" to the existing behavior is return `nil` from it.

This isn't a 100% answer to the question, but if the major modes you're working with are written according to the normal guidelines it might be the cleanest way.

Comment: That's a very good point, but a lot of minor modes could rebind the `TAB` key, like YASnippet or auto-complete for example. Do you know if such minor modes honor `(setq tab-always-indent 'complete)`?

Comment: If you want to override those minor modes, then do so.  You can still use `indent-for-tab-command` for that.  BTW, if the `complete` value of `tab-always-indent` doesn't work with yasnippet, you might like to report this as a bug (in yasnippet).

Answer (score 1):

`define-key` can accept quoted string or interactive lambdas like in this example.

```
;Static
(define-key evil-normal-state-mapr "m" 'evil-motion-state)
;Conditional
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "m" 
  (lambda () (interactive) (message "%s" major-mode)))
```

Lambda's can be replaced with named functions like my-tab-completion and used more effectively.

From define-key's docstring (Emacs 25)

```
DEF is anything that can be a key's definition:
 nil (means key is undefined in this keymap),
 a command (a Lisp function suitable for interactive calling),
 a string (treated as a keyboard macro),
 a keymap (to define a prefix key),
 a symbol (when the key is looked up, the symbol will stand for its
    function definition, which should at that time be one of the above,
    or another symbol whose function definition is used, etc.),
 a cons (STRING . DEFN), meaning that DEFN is the definition
    (DEFN should be a valid definition in its own right),
 or a cons (MAP . CHAR), meaning use definition of CHAR in keymap MAP,
 or an extended menu item definition.
 (See info node `(elisp)Extended Menu Items'.)
```