# Predicate-based dynamic key binding with default fallback

Tags: emacs, configuration, elisp, key-bindings, emacs24

I would like to override a key binding such that *whenever* the key combination is pressed a user-defined predicate function is evaluated and; if it returns non-`nil`, the function `my-cmd` is executed, otherwise `default-cmd` is executed (the one that would be executed if I pressed that key combination). In other words, something like this:

```
(define-key <SOME_MODE>-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-n")
  (lambda()
     (interactive)
     (if (my-predicate-function ...)
         (my-cmd)  ; execute my command
       (default-cmd))))  ; invoke the command that is CURRENTLY bound to C-c C-n
```

Requirements:

- The command bound to the key (`C-c C-n`) depends on the current major (or even minor mode), so rebinding the command whenever the key is pressed is strongly encouraged
- if possible, I would prefer the solution that work regardless of whether the configuration code (the solution to this problem) is executed *before* or *after* another piece of code that binds some command to the same key

Comment: Duplicate of [Conditionally change keybinding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16090517/elisp-conditionally-change-keybinding) and [Emacs key binding fallback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494096/emacs-key-binding-fallback).

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how I missed those...