# In emacs how to create a mapping to a function returned by another function?

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using emacs with evil-mode, I want to map `<leader>tt` to the function `projectile-dired` however if a dired buffer is being shown then it should be mapped to the `evil-delete-buffer`, so in essence creating a map to a toggle function.

After learning the basics of emacs lisp I came up with this solution:

```
(defun toggle-projectile-dired ()
  "Toggles projectile-dired buffer."
  (interactive)
  (or
   (when (derived-mode-p 'dired-mode)
     (evil-delete-buffer (current-buffer)))
   (projectile-dired)))

;; This is how the mapping is done
(evil-leader/set-key "tt" 'toggle-projectile-dired)
```

But what I did with this solution was to create a map to a function that in the end calls to another function.

While my solution works (and I'm fine with it) what I could not do was to return the function to be called (instead of calling it, as I did) how such approach should be written?

Or in other words, how to return a function name and make that mapping call the returning function?.

PD: This question is just for the sake of learn some elisp. Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Here is some pseudo code (javascript) of what I want to achieve:

```
function toggleProjectileDired() {
  if (derivedModeP == 'dired-mode') {
    // We're in dired buffer
    return 'evilDeleteBuffer';
  } else {
    return 'projectileDired';
  }
}

evilLeaderSetKey("tt", toggleProjectileDired());
```

My solution in pseudo code is:

```
function toggleProjectileDired() {
  if (derivedModeP == 'dired-mode') {
    // We're in dired buffer
    evilDeleteBuffer();
  } else {
    projectileDired();
  }
}

evilLeaderSetKey("tt", toggleProjectileDired);
```

As you can see, one returns the function name to be called while the other calls the function. How to return a function name to be called in elisp?

Comment: Please add some pseudo-code showing an example of what you're hoping to be able to do, because your question is ambiguous.

Comment: The question is unclear. Also, `when` always returns `nil` (unless it causes a non-local exit and does not return), so your wrapping it in `or` is useless. If you want to not execute `projectile-dired` when `evil-delete-buffer` returns non-`nil` then use `and` instead of `when` (or do something else that has the same effect).

Comment: @phils done :)..... @Drew thanks I'm newbie in emacs, I would use an `if` statement if that wouldn't work, but it worked, though I'll get that modified, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

(Caveat: I don't use `evil`, and am not familiar with its custom keybinding functions.)

The canonical approach to making a key do one thing in `dired-mode` and another thing elsewhere is to define one binding in dired's keymap, and another binding in the global keymap (or whatever is appropriate). I would recommend that you try to follow this approach in most circumstances, because it makes it much simpler to see what's happening.

However, there is a way to do what you're asking for. These pages demonstrate some variations on the approach:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/22863701
- http://endlessparentheses.com/define-context-aware-keys-in-emacs.html
- http://paste.lisp.org/display/304865

In essence you use the `:filter` facility of menu items (n.b. menus are actually fancy keymaps in Emacs) to determine the command at run-time. Note that if the filter function returns `nil`, Emacs treats it as if no binding exists in that keymap, and continues looking for a binding in the remaining keymaps; so this feature facilitates bindings which are only conditionally active.

A non-`evil` version of your example might look like this:

```el
(define-key global-map (kbd "<f6>")
  `(menu-item "" projectile-dired
              :filter ,(lambda (default)
                         (if (derived-mode-p 'dired-mode)
                             'evil-delete-buffer
                           default))))
```

Again, this would be more usual:

```el
(global-set-key (kbd "<f6>") 'projectile-dired)
(eval-after-load "dired"
  '(define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "<f6>") 'evil-delete-buffer))
```

FWIW, I actually think the general approach you started with is probably the best one in this instance. If typing KEY should always toggle `dired` in that window, then binding it to a `toggle-dired` command seems like the most self-explanatory implementation.